# Remove "Set as interpreter" label in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

When editing a Python file that starts with a shebang, Visual Studio Code adds a clickable label right above it. How can i remove this label?
See image.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You should remove the first line, something like "#!/usr/bin/env python".